# Azure Backup Vault vs Recovery Services Vault

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

Tried to search through Azure docs and google for differences. Couldn't find any answers. To me, these services are mostly identical.

Could you explain the difference between **Backup Vault** and **Recovery Services Vault**?

Answer (score 4):

"**Recovery Services vault**" was there first.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-recovery-services-vault-overview

It can back up:

- VMs (via a backup extension)
- File Shares (part of storage account)
- SQL Server / SAP HANA databases, when deployed on an Azure VM

"**Backup vault**" came later.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-vault-overview

It can back up:

- Managed disks (reads the disk directly, does not use VM extension)
- Blobs (part of storage account)
- Azure PostgreSQL databases

Notice the absence of regular SQL Server (Azure PaaS) databases: those backups are kept with the SQL Server resource itself, they are not sent to a Recovery Services or Backup vault.

Answer (score 0):

Backup Vault is what the name implies a place where backups are saved.

Recovery Services Vault provides functionality that is in addition to basic backup functionality, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-recovery-services-vault-overview